# Replacing files during silent install

Tags: deployment, windows-installer

I have created an MSI with Installshield that installs several Office addins. I've now created a new version of this installer which replaces the addins.

When I run the installation on a PC where any of the Office applications are running the add-ins files are locked and the installer pops up the FilesInUse dialog. There i can choose Ignore and the installer replaces files on reboot without shutting down the applications.

However when running silently, it automatically shuts down the applications and restarts them.

Can i force a silent install to do the same? i.e. not shutdown the applications and replace files on next reboot?

I have thought about using a RunOnce key, but I don't want to require users logging on to be administrators. We will be deploying this program with SCCM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Installers uses [Restart Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc948910%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to close running application and then restart them when update is finished. That is the best user experience: no system reboot is required. All the data and open files should be preserved in the applications after restart (of course the application has to correctly implement restart).

When files are updated on the next system restart, the system is actually in an unstable state until restart. Depending on how your Add-ins are used, it could happen that both the old and the new version are loaded either in the same process, one application uses the old version while the other uses the new version.

See [Using Windows Installer with Restart Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information on using the Restart Manager:

> Package authors and administrators can control the interaction of the Windows Installer and Restart Manager by using the [**MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370377%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [**MSIDISABLERMRESTART**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [**MSIRMSHUTDOWN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) properties and the [DisableAutomaticApplicationShutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) policy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use REBOOT Property

```
REBOOT = ReallySuppress.
```

It suppresses all restarts and restart prompts at the end of the installation.